# How to handle Web3 js privateKeyToAccount error?

Tags: web3js

How to handle Web3 js privateKeyToAccount error if I pass the wrong private key?
I am using node js v18.

```
const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount("*****");
```

If i add a try-catch block on it then the signer is not accessible outside the try block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the private key as a string:

- prefixed `0x`
- followed by 64 hex characters (representing the 256bit key)

Example:

```
const signer = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount("0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef");
console.log(signer.address); // 0xFCAd0B19bB29D4674531d6f115237E16AfCE377c
```